# Getting error while trying to implement google authentication in my local website

Tags: php, google-chrome

I'm getting following error while trying to implement google authentication in my local website.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_login_example\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187.

I surfed the given URL but it didn't provide me any useful information to eliminate the error. What is this error and what can I do to remove it.
I'm using chrome web browser and PHP-5.6.8

Answer (score 0):

```
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]);
```

Guzzle version 6

Comment: No, working on raw PHP. I saw a solution on laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/…. But it says add the path to your cacert.pem file where curl.cainfo = " " is written inside your php.ini file. I tried to find this, but couldn't find it. What should I do now?